# Can we combine multiple K-Means Models as a single model?

Tags: nlp, clustering, k-means, word-embeddings, word2vec

I have a NLP problem statement where I use a Word2Vec embedding pre-trained model to convert key text to vectors and then on a set of terms run k-means clustering to get a final model for certain `k`

For various sets of terms, I would develop a different model, which I would store to disk.

My question is, in case there is a new term, which I wish to classify as to which cluster should it point to from all the models can I follow the following approach?

1. Load all models to memory and get their cluster centers.
2. get the vector of the new term based on the same pre-trained model as before.
3. get distance from each cluster center to the new vector and whichever is nearest can be considered as the winning cluster

I would like to know what could be the possible drawbacks of such an approach.

My assumption is that since the vector space is same as defined by the pre-trained model, therefore the cluster centers would be in the same space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your assumption, the vector space is the same so I don't see any major problem with this approach.
Still this approach might cause some more subtle bias, depending on the differences between the models (sets of terms, number of clusters). I could imagine the following problems happening:

- if there is a big difference in number of clusters between models, a model which has more clusters is more likely to contain the closest match, simply because it has more centroids. This might favour the most precise clusters (this might actually be a good thing, depends).
- if there are many models sometimes there might be many close centroids across the models, and this would probably make the selection of the closest among them almost random: the exact position of a centroid is significant with respect to other centroids within the same model, not necessarily with respect to other centroids outside the model.

Comment: I feel that the only problem would be if 1 model shares an overlapping cluster with another model...As in 2 doc sets sharing the same vector space, or such a large vector space, that the clusters of 1 model may be engulfed by 1 cluster of another model...and that may lead to the larger cluster never being selected...

would that be a problem..??

Comment: Well yes, my answer is essentially about this problem (2nd point): the clusters are comparable because they are in the same vector space, but that means that clusters overlap each other across models. Keep in mind that in K-means clusters are only defined by their closest centroid, there are no bounds to decide what is inside or outside a cluster. It might be ok if the sets of terms used to generate the clusters are very distinct from each other, it depends on the data.